# C++ resize array to smaller size keep same name delete old place in array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, resize

I have an array of space object (my thing) that I need to reduce but keep the same name in order to handle some collisions.  I set my array up like:

```
ufo** ufoAr = new ufo*[numberOfUfos];
for (int i=0; i<numberOfUfos; i++) {
    ufoAr[i] = new ufo(randomIntBetween(1630, 70), randomIntBetween(860, 45));
}
```

and when i detect a collision I want to resize my array with two less and delete the two specific elems of array. like here:

```
//look through all the ufoAr[]
for (int i=0; i<numberOfUfos; i++) {
    //look through ufoAr[] again to see other objects
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        //if the same
        if (i==j){ continue; }
    else {
            //find a collision
        if(ufoAr[i]->collision(ufoAr[j]->sp)) {
                //Array::Resize(ufoAr, numberOfUfos-2);         
                //numberOfUfos = numberOfUfos - 2;
            // ------ TRY TO RESIZE ARRAY TO -2 BUT SAME NAME WITHOUT iTH AND jTH ELEM
                ufoAlive[i] = false;
            ufoAlive[j] = false;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on resizing the array, thanks in advanced. I am really struggling and need another opinion.  thanks

Jack

Comment: Since this is C++, is there any reason why you don't use `std::vector<ufo>`?

Comment: i am planing on compiling using intel icpc for a paralell machine, and use cilk_plus, and I believe vector operations are prohibited

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to FIRST create a new array, e.g.

```
ufo** ufoArTmp = new ufo*[numberOfUfos-2];
```

then copy the contents [you want to keep] of `ufoAr` into `ufoArTmp`. Once that is done, you do `delete [] ufoAr`, and finally `ufoAr = ufoArTmp;` to update the original pointer. do NOT delete `ufoArTmp` at this point, as it's the same value as is now in `ufoAr`, and you want to keep that, right.

Obviously pay special attention to `numberOfUfos` being less than 2 when you start... ;)

Edit, in reading through the other code:

Don't do this:

```
    if (i==j){ continue; }
else {
```

much better:

```
 if (i!=j) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use std::vector and let that handle the resizing for you.

[cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

[cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)